# Allow playing mp3 files in the website but prevent download from a direct link

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm having a codeigniter project for playing and downloading mp3 files. Users and admins can play mp3 files from the front-end and the back-end but users shouldn't be able to download these files except from the download controller using the download helper. That's what I did so far I added htaccess file in the sound directory to prevent direct download and it works but that prevents users from playing mp3 files at all.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And the download controller works fine to allow specific users to download these files. How to edit it to allow playing mp3 files in that directory without direct access to full download path?

I want to access mp3 files from specific pages to play it and to download it and deny any other direct access to it.

Please not that the audio element in the project uses the absolute path to the mp3 file to play it. I even tried using relative path to it but didn't play too

Comment: soundcloud will fetch the file in chunks via an api using a key unique to the file. this prevents direct access to the file. as you can imagine, any solution imo would be too broad for a q&a site

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea

Use a PHP file as the MP3...

I know this sounds weird but technically a PHP file can be interpreted as ANY file type

Your front end:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="music.php?token=as5df65s1df" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Let me explain this:
When the user visits the page, set a access token that can only be used once, set it on src and set it in session

```
$_SESSION['securePlay'] = 'as5df65s1df';
```

```
if(!isset($_GET['token'])){
  //No token? They tried to view the file
  die('access denied');
}


if($_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['securePlay']){
// The one time token hasn't been used yet
// Go ahead and mimic an MP3 and play the music

  $file = 'realMusic.mp3';

  if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }

  //Here is where you'll want to invalidate the current token and get a new one

} else {
  //The tokens don't match meaning you got a new one and the old one cant be used anymore
  die('access denied');
}
```

This does the following:
When a user visit page, hits play, it works because the token is used
When a user visits the audio src page, the get token isn't set, access denied
When a user visits the audio src page, the get was already loaded on initial load, so it's expired
If someone uses inspect to view the src file and they right-click and save the source, the token has already been used, access denied

This is NOT a bullet proof system but it's dang good for an average website

If it's a valid play, the php file will appear as an mp3 file
If it's not a valid play, it appears as a php file and access is denied

You'll also want to put the mp3 files outside of the public folder so only the php file reader can access them. The client will never see a .mp3 file and if you did decide to put the mp3 files in public view, they would have to guess the path to view it.

My recommendation is use the JS audio api and every time you want to play a song, create a new audio object and get a new token via AJAX

Note: while getting a new token, use POST or anything but get, we want to avoid the client from going to that route manually and getting a token